# Let $(f(x))^2$ and $(f(x))^3$ are $C^{\infty}$. Prove or disprove that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Suppose $f(x), -\infty < x < +\infty$, is a real valued function such that both $(f(x))^2$ and $(f(x))^3$ are $C^{\infty}$.
>
> Must $f$ be $C^{\infty}$?

I had seen this exercise somewhere on internet long ago, it is quite disturbing to post exercises where I block completely (and this is not lack of trying).

Someone could just give me a way to solve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: a stupid counterexample would be a discontinuous function taking only values $-1$ and $1$, but perhaps if you put a continuity restriction this problem gets more interesting

Comment: @mm-aops: What function with domain all of $\Bbb R$ do you have in mind?

Comment: right, as T. Bongers pointed out this won't work because of the $f^3$ thing, sorry!

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/125861/6085).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks! And it's a french paper, so happy. You can post it as an answer no ? Or close it as duplicate ?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a very nice problem. It has also been asked on MO, where it can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/125861/6085). It is a particular case of a theorem due to Henri Joris, in

> Henri Joris. *Une $C^\infty$-application non-immersive qui possède la propriété universelle des immersions*, Arch. Math. (Basel), **39 (3)**, (1982), 269–277.

His result is as follows:

> **Theorem.** If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $m,n$ are relatively prime natural numbers, and $f^m$ and $f^n$ are $C^\infty$, then so is $f$.

For a more accessible argument (still a bit more sketchy than it would be ideal), see

> Robert Myers. *An elementary proof of Joris's theorem*. Amer. Math. Monthly, **112 (9)**, (2005), 829–831.

For the specific case of $f^2$ and $f^3$, there is also a nice write-up by Tao, available [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/Expository/squarecube.dvi).

The idea of Myers's proof is simple, but some care is needed: We have $f=f^3/f^2$ in the open set $\{x\mid f(x)\ne0\}$, so $f$ is $C^\infty$ there, and we are left to argue that the expression makes appropriate sense at those points where $f(x)=0$, and is infinitely differentiable there as well. Myers argues by induction on $n$ that $f^{(n)}$ exists and is continuous at $x$. This requires an analysis by cases, depending on whether such a point $x$ is isolated or limit of other such points. The second case is easy and is essentially an application of Rolle's theorem. The first case is harder, and Myers splits it into two subcases, depending on whether all the derivatives of $f^3$ vanish at the point $x$. The case where this happens is handled easily, and we are left with the other possibility, that Myers deals with elegantly via Taylor's theorem applied to $f^3$.

Comment: Does anyone else has problems accessing Tao's URL?

Comment: It seems it was an error on my end. The link should be fixed now.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you

Comment: Let me ask a possibly stupid question, in the specific case $f^2$ and $f^3$. As Tao points out it easily follows that $f^k$ is smooth for all $k$. Since smoothness is OK in $\{f\neq 0\}$ we can work in the open set $\{|f|<1\}$. There the sum $\sum_kf^k$ makes sense and defines a smooth function. Since it equals $\frac{1}{1-f}$ we find that $f$ is smooth in the given open set $\{|f|<1\}$. Is there a problem with this argument?

Comment: The issue is to show that $ f $ is smooth at points where it vanishes. That $ f^k $ is smooth for $ k\ne1$ is indeed easy. Without knowing that $ f $ is smooth, you cannot conclude smoothness of your series. On the other hand, if we know that $ f $ is smooth, then we are done, and there is no need to consider your series.